# Usage of word ME with nouns

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, style

I found a strange usage of word ME reading one book and I wonder what the author means.
I thought this could be a misspelling of word MY but it happens alot. Or is it a special addition to show that the person doesn't know the language well?

*he's right 'cause **me** mum and **me** sister both goes off the next day*

*the cobblestones all hard against **me** knees and cold against **me** face*

*it's way too big for me and **me** clothes is way too small for her*

*"Oi'm not yet done with **me** toilet."*

Comment: The person knows his language very well... there are plenty of English dialects that use _me_ instead of _my_. That includes [pirates](http://www.yarr.org.uk/talk/)

Comment: @oerkelens this is a nice comment, better be put as an answer.

Comment: I will leave the comment for what it is - An answer should have more (reliable) sources, and I am not able to provide these at this moment :)

Comment: You should tell us what book you found this in. [Here's why](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-that-confuses-you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an "British" dialect usage (Or Irish) and would not be proper English. It would be very common in parts of England and Ireland to hear a native speaker say

> Me Mum

The formal way to say it would be "My Mother" or My mom.

Comment: I think it's more the way the word 'my' is pronounced, rather than use of the actual word 'me' . . also, it's only 'mom' in AmE. In BrE it's formally 'mum' or in some dialects, 'mam'